# How capture id session in a new page

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I have a page where i'm logging and that page pick up the session_start() that pick up the iduser of the mySQL.

According example below:

archive "usersession.php"

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['iduser']))    {

            header("location:index.html");
        }
?>
```

On that interface has a button for register form in another link that needs saving the iduser at mySQL input.

According the example below:

archive "createform.html"

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="iduser" placeholder="Código do Usuário" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['iduser']; ?>">
```

The code is saving value=0 on database (mySQL), i believe its happen because it is not capture the userid on that new interface. Can you help us?

Comment: did you instruct your server to treat `.html` files as php?

Comment: there is no mysql here and you seem to have code missing; are you present in the question or did you logout?

Comment: rename your file createform.html in createfomr.php.. and try it